# Injecting a remote EJB in a managedBean

Tags: jsf, ejb-3.0

I'm stuck since x time on how to inject a remote EJB in a managed bean of a JSF application.
I've created a simpl java application and i've come to inject the remote EJB with the lookup... and it works.
but when i come to the web application i really don't know what to do !!!

here is my EJB code:

```
@Stateless
public class Hello implements HelloRemote {

@Override
public String sayHello(String name) {

    return "Hello, "+name;
}
}
```

the Remote interface is

```
@Remote
public interface HelloRemote {

public String sayHello(String name);
}
```

in my web application i vre created i managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean
 public class MyBean {
   @EJB
   HelloRemote helloRemote;

}
```

BUT IT DOESN'T WORK :(

Comment: Please add details, what error you get in your server logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose EJB locally you have to use `@Local` on Interface.

If you want to expose both locally and remotely you have to created 2 Interfaces, one with `@Local` and one with `@Remote`.

If your JSF ManagedBean(MyBean) is running locally ie.,**Running on same  App server as EJB** you can directly inject it using `@EJB`.

If your JSF ManagedBean is running on different server, you have to use the **JNDI Registry** to look up and access the EJB.